# iOS: How to set up iOS device to serve as a Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheralmanager

I want an iOS device to tell the world it is a keyboard, and when people pair with it, it will be able to send keystrokes.

Based on a forum article, it appears I need to provide 4 services: 1800 (device info), 180f (battery), 1812 (input device), 180a (manufacturer).

I did this, and a BLE utility reports 4 services, but there's no sign of 1812.

When I attempt to pair the iOS peripheral with OS/X, OS/X gives up, and the iOS app's various peripheral delegate methods are for the most part not called (I put breakpoints in). For instance, of the characteristics I added to each service, none is read out or subscribed to.

Can anyone explain what the proper way is to advertise an input device on BLE?

Answer (score 1):

After researching this I learned that since iOS 7, Apple forbids any iOS device to serve as an input device to any other device, which is service 1812. No explanation seems to have been given.